# Problem with Invertability of Fourier Transform in Numpy

Tags: python, numpy, image-processing, fft

I'm trying to change the phase of an image in the Fourier domain pseudorandomly while keeping the magnitude same to get a noisy image. Here's the code for that:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import cv2

img_orig = cv2.imread("Lenna.png", 0)
plt.imshow(img_orig, cmap="gray");
```

[Original Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bc0db.png)

```
f = np.fft.fft2(img_orig)
mag_orig, ang_orig = np.abs(f), np.arctan2(f.imag, f.real)
np.random.seed(42)
ns = np.random.uniform(0, 6.28, size = f.shape)
ang_noise = ang_orig+ns
img_noise = np.abs(np.fft.ifft2(mag_orig*np.exp(ang_noise*1j)))
plt.imshow(img_noise, cmap="gray");
```

[Noisy Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MW9U9.png)

But when I try to reconstruct the original image by removing the noise the way I added it, I get a noisy version of the original image. Here's the code:

```
f_noise = np.fft.fft2(img_noise)
mag_noise, ang_noise = np.abs(f_noise), np.arctan2(f_noise.imag, f_noise.real)
ang_recover = ang_noise-ns
img_recover = np.abs(np.fft.ifft2(mag_noise*np.exp(ang_recover*1j)))
plt.imshow(img_recover, cmap="gray");
```

[Reconstructed Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cNCDI.png)

Any idea about why this is happening and how to remove it? I'll appreciate any help that I can get. Thank You

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add to yours code, after string

```
ns = np.random.uniform(0, 6.28, size = f.shape)
```

this make symmetric phase:

```
ns = np.fft.fft2(ns)
ns = np.arctan2(ns.imag, ns.real)
```

Answer (score 2):

After adding noise in Fourier space, your image in real space will be complex (i.e will have both a magnitude and a phase). In your case you are taking the absolute value though, probably so that you can plot it, but in doing so you are removing this phase information and altering your image when you shouldn't.

In short, I think you need to remove the `abs` in this line:

```
img_noise = np.abs(np.fft.ifft2(mag_orig*np.exp(ang_noise*1j)))
```

Comment: If I remove that then I'll get a complex ndarray which can not be plotted or saved as an image. Is there really no way around?

Comment: You want to plot the absolute value, but you should not discard the phase data. Maybe you could move the `np.abs` to inside the plot command, so that `img_noise` is not altered?

Comment: This thing is actually a part of a bigger project that I'm doing where I need to pass this noisy image in a CNN and also reconstruct it. So I can't really do that with a complex array

Comment: @ShreyDixit: If you need your inverse transform to be real-valued, then the phase you add in the frequency domain must be conjugate symmetric. As long as you preserve this symmetry in the frequency domain, your spatial-domain image will remain real-valued. But it might still have negative values, don’t use `abs`, take the real part.